# Which HTTP response status code to use when inserting an element which references a non existing element into a database?

Tags: html, database, rest, http, httpresponse

I have a table with cities that has a foreign key constraint on another table, countries. What status code should I return if the client sends a POST request with a city that references a country that doesn't exist in the countries table? I was thinking `400 BAD REQUEST`, but this seems to be related only to the syntax of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

404 Not Found would be a better option. With an error message "country not found".

Comment: Ok, I see. Would this be valid for a PUT request as well? if, for example, I'd try to change the associated country for a city to a non-existing one.

Comment: for put 404 would be valid.

Comment: If a country for a city exists and you try to delete it is not 404 because everything is found. 422 Unprocessable entity can be considered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `HTTP 422/Unprocessable Entity`

> The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors.

The `400/Bad Request` is too vague, but `404/Not found` could also fit perfectly in your case.

Comment: Would 404 also fit for a similar PUT request where the client modifies a city entry to reference a non existing country?

Comment: A PUT request should completely replace the resource, not just modify it.
But yes, it would fit.